# MVC working with id's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have this display job order action

```
public ActionResult jobOrderList(int id)
{
     var SelectedTruck = db.trucks.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id);

     List<JobOrderDetails> joList = db.joborders.Select(s => new JobOrderDetails()
     {

         id = s.id,
         DateStarted = s.date_started,
         Description = s.description,
         DateFinished = s.date_finished,
         SpareParts = s.spare_parts,
         kilometer_run = s.run,
         Quantity = s.quantity,
         truck_no = s.truck_no,
         worked_performed = s.worked_performed

     }).ToList();

     return View(joList);
}
```

how can i display the list of job orders of the selected truck variable.

Comment: If you have set up your models and the navigation properties, then `Truck` should contain a collection of `JobOrderDetails` so it should not be necessary to make a separate database call - e.g. it might be `var SelectedTruck = db.trucks.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id).Include("JobOrders");` depending on the names of your properties

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you, i will try to work with that

Comment: @StephenMuecke there is no '.Include' extension apprearing but i have this on my truck model 'public virtual ICollection<joborder> joborders { get; set; }'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are asking.

```
     var SelectedTruck = db.trucks.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id);

List<JobOrderDetails> joList = db.joborders.Where(jo => jo.truck_no == SelectedTruck.truck_no).Select(s => new JobOrderDetails()
                 {

                     id = s.id,
                     DateStarted = s.date_started,
                     Description = s.description,
                     DateFinished = s.date_finished,
                     SpareParts = s.spare_parts,
                     kilometer_run = s.run,
                     Quantity = s.quantity,
                     truck_no = s.truck_no,
                     worked_performed = s.worked_performed

                 }).ToList();
```